# Words overlapping in a Word Search game

Tags: c++, matrix

In this function the program gets the four random words generated previously from a list and randomly puts them in the 10x10 matrix.

The problem is that sometimes words from horizontal/vertical/slanting overlap each other (however words from the same category don't). I don't want them to overlap in this way

```
    void outputMatrix() {
char matrix[10][10];
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<10; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = '-';         
    }
}
getRandomWord();
srand(time(NULL));
int randPosY = (rand() % 9);
int randPosX = (rand() % 9);
int incr = 0;
bool amend;
char r; 
for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
    char randCase = (rand() % 3) + 65;

    switch (randCase) {
    case 'A': //to input words horizontally         
        if (incr == 1) {
            r1 = r2;
        }
        if (incr == 2) {
            r1 = r3;
        }
        if (incr == 3) {
            r1 = r4;
        }   

    reCheck:
        amend = false;
        if ((randPosX + strlen(dictionary[r1]) > 10)) {
            randPosX--;
            goto reCheck;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(dictionary[r1]); i++) {
            matrix[randPosY][randPosX + i] = dictionary[r1][i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(dictionary[r1]); i++) {
            reRand:
                if (matrix[randPosY][randPosX + i] != '-') {
                    randPosY = (rand() % 9);
                    randPosX = (rand() % 9);                        
                    goto reRand;
                    amend = true;

                }if ((i == (strlen(dictionary[r1]) - 1)) && (amend == true)) goto reCheck;
            }           
        break;

    case 'B': //to input words vertically           
        if (incr == 1) {
            r1 = r2;
        }
        if (incr == 2) {
            r1 = r3;
        }
        if (incr == 3) {
            r1 = r4;
        }       
    reCheck2:
        amend = false;
        if ((randPosY + strlen(dictionary[r1]) > 10)) {
            randPosY--;
            goto reCheck2;
        }           
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(dictionary[r1]); i++) {
            matrix[randPosY + i][randPosX] = dictionary[r1][i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(dictionary[r1]); i++) {
        reRand2:
            if (matrix[randPosY + i][randPosX] != '-') {
                randPosY = (rand() % 9);
                randPosX = (rand() % 9);
                goto reRand2;
                amend = true;
            }if ((i == (strlen(dictionary[r1]) - 1)) && (amend == true)) goto reCheck2;
        }
            break;

    case 'C': //to input words slanting         
        if (incr == 1) {
            r1 = r2;
        }
        if (incr == 2) {
            r1 = r3;
        }
        if (incr == 3) {
            r1 = r4;
        }

    reCheck3:
        amend = false;
        if ((randPosY + strlen(dictionary[r1]) > 10)) {
            randPosY--;
            goto reCheck3;
        }
    reCheck4:
        if ((randPosX + strlen(dictionary[r1]) > 10)) {
            randPosX--;
            goto reCheck4;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(dictionary[r1]); i++) {
            matrix[randPosY + i][randPosX + i] = dictionary[r1][i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(dictionary[r1]); i++) {
        reRand3:
            if (matrix[randPosY + i][randPosX + i] != '-') {
                randPosY = (rand() % 9);
                randPosX = (rand() % 9);
                amend == true;
                goto reRand3;
            }if ((i == (strlen(dictionary[r1]) - 1)) && (amend == true)) goto reCheck3;
        }           
        break;
        } incr++;           
    }

//for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
    //for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        //if (matrix[i][j] == '-') {
            //r = (rand() % 26) + 65;
            //matrix[i][j] = r;
        //}

    //}
//}
printf("\n\t     A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J\n\n\n\t");
for (int a = 0; a <10; a++) {
    printf("%d", a);
    printf("    ");
    for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
        printf("%c  ", matrix[a][b]);
    }       
    printf("\n\n\t");
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Do you ask us to improve your program? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. You need to ask us a specific question that we can answer.

Comment: When you determine the new coordinates for the next word, you do so for the last word and for the last orientation.  The logic of checking itself is wrong. You need a loop to check all cells, but if you find a collision, you must start over. (By the way, the `goto` style is horrible.Code like `start: if (x) {y(); goto start;}` can be rendered more naturally as ´while (x) y();`.)

Comment: C != C++ in many cases, and if you are learning one you should generally only tag the language you are writing / compiling. An answer in the other language may not work or just lead you in the wrong direction for a native solution.

Comment: Doesn't it check  the whole matrix?  The condition in the for-loop to repeat procedure is after completing checking the matrix and when there is a change in the matrix (hence the boolean ) . I cannot understand what is wrong.

Comment: You pick coords for the first word. You adjust the coords in case they go off the grid and then place the word. Then, at the end of the current iteration, you pick the coords for the next word. At that time, you don't know yet how long the next word will be nor whether you place it horizontally, vertically or diagonally and whether you need to adjust your coordianates. So you base your check on the current word and orientation. Plus, if you find a collision, you don't jump out of the `i` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic to place a word should be:

- pick a word
- pick random coordinates and an orientation until the word can be placed at these coordinates and with that orientation.
- place the word

Instead, you place the first word without checking for collision (which is okay, you've got an empty grid) and pick new coordinates after you've placed a word. At that time you don't know which word you are going to place, at which orientation you are going to place it and whether you must adjust your coordinates to prevent your word from spilling over the grid's borders.

Your code exhibits other problems:

- Your use of `goto`s makes the code nearly unreadable. You can substitute all of the `goto`s with common control constructs. For example,

  ```
  reCheck4:
      if ((randPosX + strlen(dictionary[r1]) > 10)) {
          randPosX--;
          goto reCheck4;
      }
  ```

  can be written as

  ```
  while (randPosX + strlen(dictionary[r1]) > 10) randPosX--;
  ```

  Some `goto`s make stetements unreachable, for example:

  ```
  goto reRand2;
  amend = true;
  ```

  Here `amend = true` will never be executed. (It's strange that you use the Fortran77-ish gotos all over the place, but the one place where they *might* have been clearer, you use a Pascal-ish truth variable.)
- Your loop over the four words uses `x`, but you never use that variable. Instead, you keep another variable `incr`, whose value is the same as the value of `x`. Replace

  ```
  int incr = 0;

  for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
      // Do stuff with incr, but not with x
      incr++;
  }
  ```

  with:

  ```
  for (int incr = 0; incr < 4; incr++) {
      // Do stuff with incr, but not with x
  }
  ```
- You have four word indices, `r1` through `r4`. Code like

  ```
  if (incr == 1) {
      r1 = r2;
  }
  if (incr == 2) {
      r1 = r3;
  }
  if (incr == 3) {
      r1 = r4;
  }
  ```

  which you even repeat in all three orientation cases, suggests that you want an array here:

  ```
  r1 = index[incr];
  ```
- Call `srand` only once, at the beginning of `main`. Repeatedly calling `srand` with a low-granularity seed such as the time in seconds will make your program less random.
- `strlen` is a function that determines the length of the string every time you call it by traversing the string until it finds the null terminator. You are always looking at the same string in the loop, so you can store the string length in a variable. (Yourstrings are short, and the overhead is negligible, but still.)

You can correct your code by ptting the tests up front. That will mean a null test for the first word, but at least the logic is clear.

You can improve your code in several ways:

- Try to eliminate the duplication of code. At the moment, your three cases are nearly the same. Find the common parts and coalesce them into a common function. For example, the orientations really just mean other "movement vectors" through the grid, namely (0,1) for oriontal, (0,1) for vertical and (1,1) for diagonal.
- Once you have this, you can calulate the valid ranges for the position up front. There's no need to adjust the coordinates.
- Don't be shy to use functions. Separating tasks into functions means that you must pass some data, but it also means that you can jump out of the function with a return value right away if you have to. This saves you a lot of `goto`s and truth variables and is C's way of flow control.

  Checking whether you can place a word is a good candidate for a function. Placing the word, too.
- Tim B has sugested a reset. That's a good idea, because you might pait yourself into a corner here if your words are long.

Here's a revised (or rewritten, rather) version of your code, which does not pick the words to place randomly, however:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int isvalid(char matrix[10][10], int x, int y, int dx, int dy, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (matrix[y][x] != '-') return 0;
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }

    return 1;
}

void matrix_fill(char matrix[10][10], const char *words[4])
{
    int dx[3] = {1, 0, 1};      // horizontal strides
    int dy[3] = {0, 1, 1};      // vertical strides

    startover:

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            matrix[j][i] = '-';
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        const char *word = words[i];
        int len = strlen(word);

        int orient, x, y;
        int tries = 0;
        int valid;

        if (len > 8) break;     // just to be sure

        do {
            orient = rand() % 3;
            x = rand() % (10 - dx[orient] * len);
            y = rand() % (10 - dy[orient] * len);

            valid = isvalid(matrix, x, y,
                            dx[orient], dy[orient], len);            
            tries++;
        } while (!valid && tries < 100);

        if (!valid) goto startover;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            matrix[y][x] = word[i];
            x += dx[orient];
            y += dy[orient];
        }
    }

}

void matrix_print(char matrix[10][10])
{
    printf("%4s    ", "");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%4c", 'A' + i);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        printf("%4d    ", j);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            printf("%4c", matrix[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    const char *dictionary[4] = {"apple", "pear", "cherry", "lemon"};
    char matrix[10][10];

    srand(time(NULL));

    matrix_fill(matrix, dictionary);
    matrix_print(matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Yeah you're right Goto's are not good practice I replaced them with a while.... I  also added functions and arranged the logic as you have stated first. There happened to ba another problem that the Boolean doesn't work in c++  ! I used an integer instead....The program works great now! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

When you decide to place the word in a location then first scan everywhere you are placing the word and see if there is another word. If there is then abort and try a new location.

You might want to have some sort of "reset" option as well if it fails too often just in case there is no valid place.

Comment: Doesn't it do that form where the boolean is being used?    Maybe instead of repeating the the case I repeat the whole method? I'll try once I'm at home.