# strtok error generated ::how to fix

Tags: c, exception, strtok, runtimeexception, unhandled-exception

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
char* matrix [10][10];  
int main(void){         
        int i;
          char* list[4];
         char* words[][20]={" c a t "," c a r "," b e a r "," s h i p "," m o u s e "," b e a t l e "," c o a t "," n e s t "," i c e "," s u g a r "," b a c o n "," f r o w n "," s m i l e "," d e a d "," f e a t h e r "," g o a t "," h e n "," j e l l y "," k o a l a "," l i p s "};

        int length;
        int num;
        int k;
        int m;
        char otherString=0;
        char* c;
        int j;
        int s;
        int r;


        char test[10];
        char* token;

const char *search = " ";
        char* empty="";
        int size;
        int ans;

        int x;
        int y;
        int pos;
        int pos2;
        int randRow;
        int randColumn;
        int chosen[10];
        int random;
        int d;
        int ROWS      = 10;      // number of rows
 int COLUMNS   = 10;      // number of columns




        printf("\tA\tB\tC\tD\tE\tF\tG\tH\tI\tJ\n");


        srand(time(NULL));

        for( i=0;i<4;i++){
    printf( "\n%d",i );
    d=0;
        do{
            random = (rand()%20);
            list[i]=words[0][random];
            d=0;
            for( j=0;j<i;j++){
                if(strcmp(words[0][random],list[j])==0)d=1;
            }
        }while(d);
        }


    token = strtok((words[0][random]),search); 

    while(token!=NULL) 
   {
      length=strlen(words[0][random]);

      for( k=0;k<length;k++){

        matrix [i][k]=token;

          token = strtok(NULL, search); 


            matrix [i][k]=token;

      } 
    } 


            for(r=0;r<10;r++){
            printf("\n");   
            for(s=0;s<10;s++){
            //ans=strlen(matrix[r][s]);
                /*if(ans==0){
                c= 'A' + (rand() % 26);
                matrix[r][s]=c;

            }*/
                 printf("\t%s",matrix[r][s]);


            }}


        getchar();
            return 0;
            }
```

> > basically this is my code. it compiles fine but strtok generates an
> >     exception during runtime. would appriciate fixing my bug thanks this code is meant to chose random 4 words that are not duplicate and
> >     strtok is used to seperate them to input them into matrix
> >     this still doesnt work even though answered. it does not display
> >     correct result

Comment: There are so many duplicates of this! Your strings are read-only strings defined with string literals `"like so"` and `strtok` tries to modify its source string. (It places null terminators at the end of tokens.) You can either make the strings modifiable char arrays or you must use a non-destroying tokeniser.

Comment: Your code looks as if you were trying to find words in a matrix. Anyway, all your words have single letters between spaces, e.g. `" c a t "`. You don't need tokenisation if you store the words in regular fashion, `"cat"` and then access the characters individually. Much more straightforward. (You will get characters, though, not strings. Characters lend themselves to easy comparison and are probably what you need here. Be aware of the difference, though.)

Comment: how can i put them in the matrix without strtok?

Comment: I've answered a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870936/words-overlapping-in-a-word-search-game/33873339#33873339) here on SO. In general, you shiuld be using plain `char`s, i.e. singlemcharacters, where your code uses one-letter strings of type ´char *`. For example, your matrix should be `char matrix[10][10]`, your word list `char words[][20]`.

Comment: You should also pay heed to warnings. And please remove the many unsused variables before posting here.